# Set MouseListener to JLabel inside JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlabel, mouselistener

I have one JTable which contains some columns with String and two columns for Edit and Delete. I have added ImageIcon on JLabel, and set that label in JTable for all rows. Now I want to set MouseListener for that JLabel(as there is no way to set MouseListener for ImageIcon).

How can I set MouseListener to JLabel inside JTable?

I can get which cell clicked by user, but I want to set Listener only.

Please suggest me....

Comment: what do you exactly mean by `I can get which cell clicked by user, but I want to set Listener only` ?

Comment: You can add a `MouseListener` to the `JTable` and when the user clicks on the table then get the column of the click. If the column is your `ImageIcon` column then do the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found there is no way to add direct listner to components inside JTable. You have to go with JTable's listener only.

Comment: typically, there _are no_ components inside a JTable: cell content is shown using renderers (a kind of stamp for painting) - be sure you understand the concept of renderers and editors, f.i. by reading the relevant chapter in the online tutorial referenced in swing tag wiki :-)